# Does $K$-theoretical Atiyah-Singer index formula hold for non-compact manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, topological-k-theory

In famous [*The Index of Elliptic Operators: I*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970715) Atiyah and Singer introduce two families of morphisms:
$$\text{a-ind}^X,\, \text{t-ind}^X\colon K(TX)\to \mathbb Z$$
indexed by *compact* smooth manifolds $X$.
The index theorem says that $\text{a-ind}^X = \text{t-ind}^X$.

However in the proof they define an *excision* property that essentially allows one to define analytical and topological indices for *every* (non-compact) smooth manifold, basically by using any embedding into a compact manifold.

> My understanding is that we can write $\text{a-ind}^X = \text{t-ind}^X$ for *every* (not necessarily compact) manifold $X$.

Have I missed an important point? Is there any reason why the theorem wasn't formulated as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed an important point. Excision holds under *open* embeddings into compact manifolds – and [this is not always possible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22441/compactification-theorem-for-differentiable-manifolds).